# How to manage the height of UITextField when keyboard appears on the click?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, xcode4

I am having dynamic cells and the height of each cell is 450, in the that there is a UITextField So problem is that if I clicked on the textfield when it's on the height of view 350 the keyboard hide the textfield and when scroll little above the cell and clicked than its not hidden..

I have set the height on textfield begin and endEditing but not worked all the time while scrolling...because I don't know the exact position of UITextField.

So how to set the UItextField height dynamic when the tableview scrolls?

Answer (score 2):

You should not change the text field's height. You can scroll the tableview upwards to make the text field visible when the key board is up. Use `setContentOffset` method to scroll the table view.

```
CGPoint offset = [textField convertPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0) toView:tableView];
[tableview setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, offset)];
```

Comment: Thanks for replying but i still not get the proper solution, actually i dont know the exact positon of text field . so if i applied setContentOffset y=100; then it does'nt work for all the textfields.

Comment: You have to dynamically calculate the offset. Try my updated code.